# Setting up textboxes in same straight line

Tags: java, android, user-interface, textbox

Please have a look at the following code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/firstNumber"
        />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/firstNumberTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/secondNumber"
        />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/secondNumberTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

    </LinearLayout>



         <RadioGroup
             android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             >

             <RadioButton 
                 android:id="@+id/sum"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="@string/sum"
                 />

             <RadioButton 
                 android:id="@+id/min"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="@string/min"
                 />

             <RadioButton 
                 android:id="@+id/max"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="@string/max"
                 />

             <RadioButton 
                 android:id="@+id/dev"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="@string/dev"
                 />
         </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

The output GUI of this code is attached as an image
[image]

However, you can see that one text box is starting before the other one, making the GUI ugly. I need to display the textboxes in the same column, in a one straight line. For an example, if the text box 1 is starting at X=1 and Y=1, the second textbox should start in X=1 and Y=2, this example is in case of Java. Please help!

Comment: Use relative layout and align on the left.... i'll write something for you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fixed size for your TextViews (e.g. `android:layout_width="20dip"` for both Views). Or use [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) for displaying two columns: the first column will store TextViews, the second one will have EditTexts.

Comment: why r u using "dip" and not "dp" ? I have seen "0dp" and those stuff, this is the first time I am seeing the size adjustment with "dip". Are they different?

Comment: they are just exactly the same thing - dimension independent pixels.

Comment: Remember, when you later decide to extend your application and want to port it to different resolutions/devices, this table will bite you in your ass so hard that you will *rewrite* your gui XMLs rather than taking the tables out of them. With a deadline and numerous other (android) bugs, you probably don't want to waste your time on this. Leave tables to HTML designers, use RelativeLayout when you want to put something on the same spot as something else. This is a true, production story. Think ahead :)

Answer (score 1):

Lemme try

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/firstNumber"
    android:alignParentLeft="true"
    android:alignParentTop="true"
    />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/firstNumberTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:toRightOf="@+id/firstTextView"
    android:marginLeft=30dp 
    />

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/secondNumber"
    android:alignLeft="@+id/firstTextView"
    android:below="@+id/firstTextView"
    />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/secondNumberTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:alignLeft="@+id/firstNumberTxt"
    android:below="@+id/firstTextView"
    />

     <RadioGroup
         android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

         <RadioButton 
             android:id="@+id/sum"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/sum"
             />

         <RadioButton 
             android:id="@+id/min"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/min"
             />

         <RadioButton 
             android:id="@+id/max"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/max"
             />

         <RadioButton 
             android:id="@+id/dev"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/dev"
             />
     </RadioGroup>
```

EDIT:

so it's not android:below, it's

```
  android:layout_below="@+id/listActiveChat"
```

and

```
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mesagge_edit"
```

Comment: Trust me man, you *really* want to avoid using all layouts other than relative one if you can....

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what is your android version? I am using 2.2 and I cant see those alignment xml codes!

Comment: @Kzinch: yes i am. your code doesn't scale well with different resolutions and different fontsizes, mine disregards that issue.

Sepala, the relative layout has been there since API level 1. check the edit.

Comment: Big problem! They are not in my thing!! What's wrong? +1 from me anyway

Comment: @ Shark most of your attributes are lacking the `layout_` prefix. I vote up as I strongly recommend RelativeLayout in such a case. @Kzinch a solution with given dp values will *not* scale well per definition. Both solutions have there pro and cons but fixed dp and a TableLayout for that is not needed.

Comment: @Sepala if you can't find some of the attributes, try adding `layout_` before them. Try `android:layout_toRightOf` etc

Comment: Man, this `android:marginLeft=30dp` is such a dirty trick. Do you always use some magickal constants to make a proper layout?

Comment: @Kzinch Sometimes i use negative margins too to make things overlap :) It could be replaced with a more elegant trick, or omitted. But 30dp is really a nice value ;) Tables always reminded me of how much I hate(d) HTML. This is like the android's gridbag layout.

Comment: no I don't have them. I only have width, height, weight, gravity, margin, marginLeft, marginTop, marginRight and marginBottom. What's wrong?

Comment: I do believe this answer is more accurate