# Some attributes are not available when "Minimum SDK" is less than the Build SDK

Tags: android

I just faced to a weired problem in Android. That is, I created my project in eclipse using default settings. Eclipse has applied "Android 2.3.3 (API10) as the "Build SDK" and "API8:Android 2.2 (Froyo)" as the "Minimum required SDK.

However, I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014440/setting-up-textboxes-in-same-straight-line/13014536#comment17662128_13014536) and they have asked me to use the attribute "`android:layout_toRightOf`" but that attribute wasn't available!! Following were the attributes available which starts with `android:layout_`, they are width, height, weight, gravity, margin, marginLeft, marginTop, marginRight and marginBottom.

However, then I opened another project with "Android 2.3.3 (API10) as the "Build SDK" and  the same as the "Minimum required SDK". Now, those attributes are there!!

Why is this? Do I have to select the same API as the build sdk and minimum required sdk? Please help!

**EDIT**

Following code has those attributes, which didn't appear when I am trying to use at the first time

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/firstNumber"
    android:alignParentLeft="true"
    android:alignParentTop="true"
    />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/firstNumberTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:toRightOf="@+id/firstTextView"
    android:marginLeft=30dp 
    />

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/secondNumber"
    android:alignLeft="@+id/firstTextView"
    android:below="@+id/firstTextView"
    />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/secondNumberTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:alignLeft="@+id/firstNumberTxt"
    android:below="@+id/firstTextView"
    />

     <RadioGroup
         android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

         <RadioButton 
             android:id="@+id/sum"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/sum"
             />

         <RadioButton 
             android:id="@+id/min"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/min"
             />

         <RadioButton 
             android:id="@+id/max"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/max"
             />

         <RadioButton 
             android:id="@+id/dev"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/dev"
             />
     </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: the xml attribute "layout_toRightOf" has been around since API 1. It will only exist if you are editing a view within a relative layout

Comment: That what I was doing I guess. Please have a look at the code in the link I have mentioned. It is not big code at all

Comment: You are using "android:toRightOf="@+id/firstTextView"" in the XML you posted. it should be android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstTextView". Same with aligns.. they should be layout_alignLeft

Comment: nope.I have mentioned I have used it in the correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a RelativeLayout? toRightOf is only available in that kind of layouts!

Comment: Yes, I think. Please have a look at the link I have mentioned, it is a code, not big at all :)

Comment: please post your xml layout ;)

Comment: I will take the code which was in an answer to my question there. That one has those attributes